# Pocketsphinx on Android - VoiceCommands to activate voice recording

Tags: android, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I have been searching for a tool that would allow me to do voice commands in order to start a recording and to stop it.
For that i would only need three commands(?): initialization command(not sure), start command and stop command.

With that in mind would it be better to use a grammar or just a file. I am working with a grammar at the moment, but it the switch search doesnt work fine.

Plus, is it possible to say "start", the user records whatever he wants, and when a "stop" is said, it stops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> With that in mind would it be better to use a grammar or just a file. I am working with a grammar at the moment, but it the switch search doesnt work fine.

You need to use keyword spotting mode as described [in tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm).

> Plus, is it possible to say "start", the user records whatever he wants, and when a "stop" is said, it stops?

Yes, it is possible, though it is better to use keyphrase of 4-5 syllables. For example "stop recording" and "start recording".

Also, to record and recognize in the same time you need to modify pocketsphinx-android sources. Instead of RecognizerThread class you need to use your own class that records and recognizes speech simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. I already created the file. 
Gonna search about the later.